# C# code inside aspx to fill gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have GridView.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <Columns>                           
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="status" ItemStyle-Width="100px" > <ItemStyle Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
                          </asp:BoundField>

                        </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

In codeBehind

```
GridView1.DataSource = DataTable1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

In aspx file I want to write some c# code. For example the following
if status == 0 then set column value equal to 'zero';
If status == 1 then set column value equal to 'one';

How to change

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="status" ItemStyle-Width="100px" > <ItemStyle Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
```

so that above written algorithm works?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use templatefields, for example:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# ReturnText(Eval("Status")) %>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

in C# codebehind

```
protected string ReturnText(object val)
{
   if(val!=null)
   {

      if(val.ToString().Equals("1")) {return "one"; }
      else if(val.ToString().Equals("0")) {return "zero";}
   }
   return "";
}
```

Another option is to return text from SQL query:

```
SELECT STATUS, 
CASE STATUS WHEN 1 THEN 'One' WHEN 0 THEN 'Zero' END As Status_Text
FROM YourTable
```

Then you can bind the column status_text to the boundfield.